# Kubernetes with route fanout - Basic understanding of Service setup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have questions about my basic understanding about the setup of my k8s cluster.

I have a K8s running on Hetzner-cloud and allocated a "physical" `Loadbalancer` (which can be controlled via `annotations` on a Service.)
I use a nginx (or traefik) as my `ingress-controller`.

Please correct me if I am wrong:

1. I create the service `Loadbalancer` with the `annotations` in the same `namespace` of my `ingress-controller` right?
2. Then I create an `ingress` with label `kubernetes.io/ingress-controller=nginx` in my `default` namespace with the settings to point to my services in the `default` namespace (one for frontend, one for backend)

**Is this the correct way to set this up?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I create the service Loadbalancer with the annotations in the same
> namespace of my **ingress-controller** right?

No ideally your ingress controller will be running in different namespace in which your workload must not be running.

You should be keeping only the **Nginx** service with `type : Loadbalancer` other services of your workload should be `ClusterIP`.

So all your traffic comes inside the cluster from one point. Your flow will be something like

```
DNS > LB > Ingress > Service > Pods > Container
```

> Then I create an ingress with label
> kubernetes.io/ingress-controller=nginx in my default namespace with
> the settings to point to my services in the default namespace (one for
> frontend, one for backend)

You mentioned **label** ideally, it should be an **annotation** `kubernetes.io/ingress-controller=nginx`.

Yes, it's perfect. You can create different ingress with different annotation rules as per requirements for different services that you want to expose publicly.

Keep your workload in **default** namespace for the controller you can use different namespaces like `ingress-controller` in future also if you have any requirement of setting up the Monitoring tools also you can create namespace and use it for monitoring only.

Answer (score 1):

1.- No. Ingress Controller and your workload doesn't have to be in the same namespace. In fact, you will have the Ingress Controller running in a separate namespace than your workload.

2.-Yes. Generally speaking your `Ingress` rules, meaning your `Ingress` object, meaning your `Ingress` yaml and your `Service` must be in the same namespace. So `Ingress` can't transpass a namespace.

**Note: There is a way to have an `Ingress` object to send trafffic to a `Service` in a different namespace.**

Comment: To point 1: Where to put the Service `type: LoadBalancer`? I use Rancher and cannot select `traefik` in system namespace when `type: LoadBalancer`was created in Project scope `default` ( in default i put all my workloads... , in "system" I put cloud-controller, volume-drivers... as well I thought  traefik-ingress-controllers ). With your suggestion I have to place "traefik" in my "default" project group, right?

Comment: ooooh. that's the `Service` pointing to the Ingress Controller? In that case, yes, it goes in the same namespace. I though you were talking about your the services of your workloads. Sorry.